# AngularJs Modal set default value from rootScope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have problem with angular modal value.
I have $rootScope and on button im opening modal which contains , and I can't set default / selected value to that

```
<form>
    <input type="button" class="mobileUpdate" ng-click="openMobileUpdateModal()" />

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="mobileModal.html">
         <form name="modalForm">
             <div class="modal-body">
                   <p>Country</p>
                   <select id="countryMobile" ng-model="countryMobile" class="select-styled" name="countryMobile" required>
                       <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.name}}</option>
                   </select>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                 <input type="button" ng-click='confirm()' value="OK"/>
                <input type="button" ng-click='cancel()' value="Cancel"/>
             </div>
         </form>
     </script>

</form>


   $rootScope.openMobileUpdateModal = function () {

      $rootScope.countryMobile = $rootScope.country;
      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'mobileModal.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl
      });
    };
    var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($rootScope, $modalInstance) {
        $rootScope.confirm = function () {
         //do something
          $modalInstance.close();
        };
        $rootScope.cancel = function () {
          $modalInstance.dismiss();
        };
    };
```

Anyone know how to send value from $rootScope to modal, and set that value as default?
Thanks

Comment: Where have you defined `countries`. can you paste that code here?

Comment: It's a list all countries. Maybe that is problem, because there is maybe 200 countries, and ng-model isn't initialized when angular want to set default value...

Comment: hmm.. that is only problem. You should initialize it inside `openMobileUpdateModal` function.

Comment: I did...
 $rootScope.countryMobile = $rootScope.country; it's inside openMobileUpdateModal function, but I can't get selected value.

Comment: It should work. create fiddle then I can solve it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is syntax error you have double quote twise in you select tag code. Update it as below then try. And use `$root` in your ng-model.

```
<select id="countryMobile" ng-model="$root.countryMobile" class="select-styled" name="countryMobile" required>
      <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It's not working, I don't have value in $root.countryMobile in modal.
Once I change select option, I see value in model.

Comment: Any error there? For $rootScope variable, you should use $root otherwise not.

Comment: Make sure that the value which is in countryMobile scope variable is one of the `country.id`.

Comment: yes it is... When I do setTimeout(function(){
         $('#countryMobile').val($rootScope.country);},100); in openMobileUpdateModal() it's working... But I don't want to do in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your problem correct but try do not use rootScope or modify and avoid rootScope modification.

If you need use some value from rootScope:

1. extract this value to local scope of particular controller and
   after that use it
2. Use WATCH operator to avoid situations when you
   render some value before it initialised.

Answer (score 0):

`<option ng-repeat>` does not work in angularjs.
you should use

```
<select id="countryMobile" ng-model="countryMobile" class="select-styled"   name="countryMobile" required ng-options="country.id as country.name for country in contries"></select>
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: I can do that also, but I can't set default value on my select.

Comment: Its not like that. You can use ng-repeat with <option>. ng-options is just standard/angular way to do this.

Comment: you have to use ng-options because ng-model of select does not respect your option's value. Even more - if there option vith value that looks like value of ng-model - angular will create new option with fake value just to not interfere with yours. Thats why your "default" don't work.